# Do processed meats cause cancer only insomuch as they contain preservatives?

Tags: nutrition

For those not in the know, the WHO released a study today saying that [Bacon, hot dogs and other processed meats cause cancer](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/wonkblog/wp/2015/10/26/hot-dogs-bacon-and-other-processed-meats-cause-cancer-world-health-organization-declares/). They further say that red meat "probably" causes cancer. A common reply to the various comment threads is something along [this conversation](https://twitter.com/cathysfo/status/658664133349482496)

[image: twitter processed meats]

So people give themselves a pass with this research with the excuse "I eat locally sourced, hipster raised, nanobatch smoked bacon so I'm ok".

Is this a valid reaction? Or does the research cover all processed meats, regardless of preservatives?

Comment: FWIW: sodium nitrate is not necessary in processed meats (only in *cased* meats such as sausages where salmonella might be a problem).

Comment: @Sklivvz true, though many processed meats do contain these known carcinogens which might explain the study results (this may be the underlying causal factor). It also leaves open the possibility that processed meats without nitrates, etc don't cause cancer

Comment: Your claim is "I eat locally sourced, hipster raised, nanobatch smoked bacon so I'm ok"? Can you show examples of people making this claim?

Comment: @Oddthinking: http://forums.theregister.co.uk/forum/1/2015/10/26/who_processed_meat/#c_2676934, not exactly a 'claim', a suggestion maybe.

Comment: The WHO says eating processed meat (as a group) increases risk of cancer. It is legitimate to ask "Are there any exceptions? Is it the preservatives? Is it one particular preservative?" but they aren't claims. Some random tweeter (with 128 followers) suggests it is Sodium nitrate as a factor, but that's not a notable claim by itself and it isn't the question being asked.

Comment: For what it's worth, I actually bought 'organic' bacon for this exact reasons, unfortunately it tasted a bit like anchovies (and cost $40/kg) so we had to abort the plan.